# scrolling when contained in a flex box

Tags: css, flexbox, scrollbar

I am really struggling to make scrolling work as I want inside a set of nested flex box containers.  What is more I am seeing weird side effects that are not making sense to me at all.

The actual site I am working on is full of custom elements, but to simplify the problem I built a test page out of regular elements (those that are custom elements in the actual app have the class "custom" added to them) and so others can see what I taking about this trial page is at https://www.chandlerfamily.org.uk/trial.html

The html is here

```html
  <body>
    <div class="main-app custom">
      <header class="main-header">Main Header Bar</header>
      <section class="main-section">
        <div class="page-manager custom">
          <div class="managed-page custom">
            <div class="page-template custom">
              <header class="secondary-header">Secondary Header</header>
              <section class="container">
                <div class="list-manager custom">
                  <header class="list-header">List Header</header>
                  <section class="list scrollable">
                    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
                    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
                  </section>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
```

What I am trying to do is make inner section scroll, snapping to its items when they don't fit on the page.  I want the scroll bars to be on that inner section, so the various headers that surround it all show in place.  Ultimately I would also like `section` labelled with the class "main-section" also be scrollable - but only to scroll at that level IF there is not a lower level scrollable section.

The css I am using is below.  The only strange thing I may need to explain is the use of `column-reverse` in the flex for the `main-app`.  This is because the ultimate app might be on a mobile, so (dependant on media queries) I am putting the header near the thumbs.  This does have a strange effect on the result, in that when in Chrome dev tools I disable that particular css line and the header pops to the top, a vertical scroll bar appears at the top level where as it doesn't at all when that is in place.

```css
      html {
        background: #ffffff;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        height:100vh;
        width:100vw;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        color: #333;
      }
      .custom {
        height:100%;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;

      }
      .main-app {
        flex-direction: column-reverse ;
      }
      header {
        background-color: #42d9ff;
        flex: 0 1 64px;
        height:64px;
      }
      section {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
      }
      .scrollable {
        overflow-y: auto; 
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      }
      .item {
        height: 50px;
        scroll-snap-align:start;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
        margin:0 5px 5px 3px;
      }
      .page-template {
        margin: 40px auto 40px auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        padding: 20px;
        min-width: 500px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
      }
```

So apart from the condundrum about why a scroll bar appears and not when I change `column-reverse` to `column` and vice versa.  I have other issues.

1. why is the Main Header Bar not 64 pixels high like the others, despite specifically being told to be 64px high. I can see no difference in the definition.
2. Why to a get no scroll bars at all, despite the innermost section having `overflow-y: auto;` yet no other element marked as scrollable.
3. I can find no mention is specs as to how the browser chooses which item to add scroll bars to, other than if content is larger that its parent and the parent has overflow: scroll or auto. How does it choose?
4. Is the fact I got scroll bars at the top level due to content with overflow:visible going beyond the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is with the `section` css

the problem is that `flex-shrink`, means that with a 1 this content shrinks along with everything else. As a result it does not overflow and force scroll bars. `flex-shrink` needs to be 0 , which means that when the content will not fit inside its container it will not shrink.  This forces scrollbars to occur on its parent.

This change also deals with the header size being to small.  It too had also been forced to shrink.  Again the solution is to set the `flex-shrink` factor to 0.

I also think that working inside to out with this, that the correct level gets scrollbars because once it has, its height is then fine for its parent and so on up the hierarchy.

I guess also that scroll bars at the top level come if content just cannot fit in the window and the body level.